Authorization for Google Drive in Android Studio
I need to write a client for Google Drive. I tried to do authentication and authorization, but when I try to send a request to Google Drive to get all the files from the drive, I get the error 401 unauthorized.
Here I authenticate through the credential manager and receive a token.
class LogginViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _loginResult = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val loginResult: LiveData<Boolean> get() = _loginResult

    private val _loginData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val loginData: LiveData<String> get() = _loginData

    fun signInGoogle(context: Context) {
        val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context)

        val getGoogleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
            .setServerClientId("77699025246-l0t92qgqq3bc8d699vj3o5cixxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .setNonce(generateNonce())
            .build()
        

        val request: GetCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
            .addCredentialOption(getGoogleIdOption)
            .build()

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            try {
                val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
                    request = request,
                    context = context,
                )

                val credential = result.credential

                val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential
                    .createFrom(credential.data)

                val googleIdToken = googleIdTokenCredential.idToken

                _loginData.value = googleIdToken
                _loginResult.value = true

            } catch (e: androidx.credentials.exceptions.GetCredentialException) {
                _loginData.value = "1" + e.message
                _loginResult.value = false
            } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
                _loginData.value = "2" + e.message
                _loginResult.value = false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun generateNonce(): String {
        val rawNonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val bytes = rawNonce.toByteArray()
        val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
        val digest = md.digest(bytes)
        return digest.fold("") {str, it -> str + "%02x".format(it) }
    }
}

Here I send a request to which I pass the user token. But in response I get a 401 error. What am I doing wrong?
class MenuViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _driveFiles = MutableLiveData<List<com.google.api.services.drive.model.File>>()
    val driveFiles: LiveData<List<com.google.api.services.drive.model.File>> get() = _driveFiles

    fun fetchDriveFiles(googleIdToken: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
                val JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()

                val credential = GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(googleIdToken)

                val driveService = Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Drive API Kotlin Example")
                    .build()

                val result: FileList = driveService.files().list()
                    .setPageSize(10)
                    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                    .execute()

                val files = result.files
                if (files != null && files.isNotEmpty()) {
                    _driveFiles.postValue(files)
                } else {
                    _driveFiles.postValue(emptyList())
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}

enter image description here
